# Create file in jsp servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets

When I create a file in java `servlet`, I can't find that file for opening. This is my code in `servlet`:

```
FileOutputStream fout;
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream("title.txt");
        new PrintStream(fout).println(request.getParameter("txttitle"));
        fout.close();
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("txttitle"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("I can't create file!");
    }
```

Where I can find that file?

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: Send text from client side to this servlet!

Comment: Then its writing? I dont see that text anywhere in your code that you pasted?

Comment: This text posted from client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create file first as in

```
File f = new File("title.txt");
fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

then you use `getAbsolutePath` to return the location of where it has been created

```
System.out.println (f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: When I create file this way, that create in eclipse root directory!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have'nt specified any directory for the file, it will be placed in the default directory of the process that runs your servlet container.

I would recommand you to always specify the full path of your your file when doing this kind of things.

If you're running tomcat, you can use System.getProperty("catalina.base") to get the path of the tomcat base directory. This can sometimes help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file object and make sure the file exists:-

```
File f = new File("title.txt");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
new PrintStream(fout).println(request.getParameter("txttitle"));
fout.close();
System.out.println(request.getParameter("txttitle"));
}
```

If the servlet cannot find the file give the full path to the file specified, like `new File("D:\\Newfolder\\title.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

you should check first if the file doesn't exist ,create it

```
if(!new File("title.txt").exists())
{
   File myfile = new File("title.txt");
    myfile.createNewFile();
}
```

then you can use FileWriter or FileOutputStream to write to the file i prefer FileWriter

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("title.txt");
writer.write("No God But Allah");
writer.close();
```

simply simple